# Efficient ways of converting in between numpy boolen into two states with Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

The objective is to create a boolean array, `state`, from another boolean array, `initial`, according to the rules described below.

If `initial` starts with `False`, the first and subsequent elements of `state` will be `False`. Upon reaching `True` in `initial`, `state` will switch to `True`.

Example:

```
initial: [False, False, False, True]
state: [False, False, False, True]
```

If, on the other hand, `initial` starts with `True`, the first and subsequent elements of `state` will also be `True`. Upon reaching `True` in `initial`, state will switch to `False`.

Example:

```
initial: [True, False, False, True]
state: [True, True, True, False]
```

If `True` is encountered in the middle of `initial`, the new value of `state` will depend on the previous state. For example, if the previous value of `state` was `False`, then `state` will switch to `True`:

```
initial: [False, False, False, True]  --Take note of the last boolean
state: [False, False, False, True]  --Take note of the last state i.e., False
```

On the other hand, if the previous value of `state` was `True`, then `state` will switch to `False`:

```
initial: [False, False, False, True]  --Take note of the last boolean
state: [True, True, True, False]  --Take note of the last state i.e., False
```

Based on these requirements and two simple samples of `initial`, I've written the following code:

```
import numpy as np

sample_1 = [False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
# sample_2  = [True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]

expected_output = []
counter = 0
for x in np.array(sample_1):
    if x == False and counter == 0:
        idx = False
    elif x == True and counter == 0:
        idx = True
        counter = 2
    elif x == False and counter == 1:
        idx = True
    elif x == True and counter == 1:
        idx = True
        counter = 0
    elif x == True and counter == 2:
        idx = False
        counter = 0
    expected_output.append(idx)
```

The expected output, respectively for `sample1` and `sample2` is:

For `sample_1`:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

For `sample_2`:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

I am curios whether there is more compact notation or a build-in module that can be used instead of the naive if-else approach above.

Comment: I don't understand how your initial examples explain how your expected output at all

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Mad Physicist, I have change the explanation for the second point. Thing should be much more clearer now

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now

Comment: Why are you using `numpy`?  It won't improve anything in the code you're showing.

Comment: @MarkRansom. It most certainly would. Why would it not?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the only place `numpy` is used in that code is a single statement: `for x in np.array(sample_1)`.  Why would that be better than `for x in sample_1`?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, hopefully to make it more clear. If you don't like my edits, please consider reverting.

Comment: @MarkRansom. I agree that that particular example can be done without numpy, but there are lots of (good) questions in which the OP recognizes that numpy would benefit them, just don't know how to use it.

Comment: Shouldn't the 6th element of the output of `sample_2` be `False` according to your computation rules?

Comment: @MarkRansom, the upstream for this code is based on `numpy` hence that what is portrait in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this gives what you want

```
import numpy as np

def compute_states(initial: np.array):
    return (initial.cumsum() % 2).astype(bool)
```

Test:

```
print(compute_states(np.array([False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False])))
print(compute_states(np.array([True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False])))
```

Output:

```
[False False False False False  True  True  True  True False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True False False False False  True  True  True  True]
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, your `if/else` can be greatly simplified. Notice that any time you get a `True` element, the value of future elements in the output is toggled.

You can therefore safely always start your loop with the assumption that prior elements were `False`:

```
state = False
for x in sample_1:
    if x:
        state = not state
    expected_output.append(state)
```

A similar approach with a counter:

```
counter = 0
for x in sample_1:
    if x:
        counter += 1
    expected_output.append(bool(counter % 2))
```

You can if course do this with numpy functions. A term that I've heard for this type of operation is "smearing a mask". The general idea is that you can build a mask with runs of elements by taking the cumulative sum of an array containing `1`, `0` and `-1` elements. `1` turns on a run, and `-1` turns it off.

To convert your input data into a more useful format, use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(sample_1)
```

Now make an intermediate array that will contain your `+/-1` values. I'm going to suggest using `np.int8` for that. First, it takes up less space, and second, you can do the entire operation in-place if you're clever:

```
triggers = np.zeros(len(sample_1), dtype=np.int8)
```

Place ones at every other index location:

```
triggers[indices[::2]] = 1
```

Place negative ones at every other location:

```
triggers[indices[1::2]] = -1
```

The output mask is just the cumulative sum of the triggers:

```
expected_output = np.cumsum(triggers).astype(bool)
```

You can do the same operation without allocating a single temporary array in the last step, because `np.bool_` and `np.int8` have the same element size:

```
expected_output = np.cumsum(triggers, out=triggers).view(np.bool_)
```

Comment: Really appreciate for the suggestion and especially introduction of the memory-efficient `dtype`

Comment: @balandongiv. No prob. You can do the selected answer in-place too using a similar trick.